# Why isn't my onClick method being called from an inflated view in my custom fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom Fragment that inflates it's content from test.xml

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, true);
    return v;
}
```

Inside of test.xml, I have a toggle button defined like so:

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="update"
    />
```

When I click on the toggle button, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a method update(View) in the activity class 
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class 
android.widget.ToggleButton
```

I have the following method defined in both the calling activity and the fragment, but neither is getting called:

```
public void update(View view) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "starting update!");
}
```

I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are creating the LayoutInflater you are creating, probably, with the ContextThemeWrapper and to work you need to create with the activity context.

I had similar problem. I was creating like this:

(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

then I done like this:

(LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

and worked.

I hope I have helped.

Comment: This enabled the associated Activity to handle the onClick, thanks! Is there a way to get the Fragment to handle it?

Comment: This way, I dont thing so. If you want the Fragment to handle it, you need to add android:id="@+id/theid" on the ToggleButton on the test.xml, and on the onCreateView method you need to put                                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, true);                    ToggleButton tg = (ToggleButton) v.findResourceById(R.id.theid)     tg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(...)). This way I think will work.